# August Movie Event #1!

Tags: discussion, movie-night

UPDATE: As the result was a draw, I've chosen [the answer with the single highest number of upvotes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7110/20774) as the winner; 8 versus 6.

---

OK, SFF:SE peeps. It's time to choose the first group-viewing event film for August!

As before, you need to pick your preferred film and post it as an answer below. Upvote the ones you like and the top answer (by Tuesday 11th August at midnight UTC) will be selected as the winner. We'll then watch together on Thursday 13th August at 10pm UTC in the [Mos Eisley chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley).

Choose wisely and remember, <s>all</s> most suggestions will be considered  carefully, with <s>no exceptions</s> [very few exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield_Earth_(film)).

[image]

Comment: I repeat my suggestions of *Manos: Hand of Fate* or *Plan 9 From Outer Space*

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - I'd upvote Plan 9

Comment: Are TV series allowed? Could I nominate something from Doctor Who, say?

Comment: @randal'thor - I'm going to say no. I want this to be self-contained and as accessible as possible. That's not to say I'm not interested in the idea. Perhaps we could trial it in chat after the film event?

Comment: TV series doesn't necessarily mean not self-contained! Some DW (and ST?) episodes can work great as stand-alone films.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you make a single question for each individual event instead of just using a continuous one (and deleting the answers already done), so that votes can accumulate and one doesn't have to resubmit the same things each and every time?

Comment: @TARS - Yes, because that would give a huge advantage to those answers (films) there were left over from the last time around

Comment: @Richard Hmm, ok, if that's to be seen as a disadvantage I could see your point.

Comment: When's the next event going to be?

Comment: I thought bi-weekly would be right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I nominate the classic movie *The Day the Earth Stood Still*, starring Michael Rennie and Patricia Neal, which is available on [Netflix](http://www.netflix.com/WiMovie/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still/60026578?sod=search-autocomplete).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still):

> In 1995 The Day the Earth Stood Still was selected for preservation in the United States National Film Registry as "culturally, historically, or aesthetically significant".
>
> The Day the Earth Stood Still also received recognition from the American Film Institute. **In 2001, it was ranked number 82 on 100 Years...100 Thrills, a list of America's most heart-pounding films**.  **It placed number 67 on a similar list 100 Years...100 Cheers, a list of America's most inspiring films**.  In June 2008, the American Film Institute revealed its "10 Top 10" — the best ten films in ten "classic" American film genres — after polling over 1,500 people from the creative community. **The Day the Earth Stood Still was acknowledged as the fifth best film in the science fiction genre.**
>
> The film was also on the ballot for AFI's other lists including 100 Years...100 Movies, the tenth anniversary list, 100 Years...100 Heroes and Villains for Klaatu in the heroes category, 100 Years...100 Movie Quotes for the famous line "Gort! Klaatu barada nikto!", and AFI's 100 Years of Film Scores.  In 2004, the film was selected by The New York Times as **one of The Best 1000 Movies Ever Made.**

I repeat for emphasis:

> ### "The Day the Earth Stood Still was acknowledged as the fifth best film in the science fiction genre."

It's also the only movie I know of that had the balls to say "Stop obsessing about Communism, you childish jerks" at the height of the "Red Scare", and even cast a blacklisted "Communist sympathizer" in a major role.

[image]

Comment: In this situation Original >>> Remake.

Comment: It's been ages since I've seen this. You have my +1

Answer (score 3):

Since Manos: Hand of Fate didn't go over well, I suppose it's time to bring out the big guns.

The movie popularly considered the worst movie ever made:

[*Plan 9 From Outer Space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space) (not to be confused with [*Plan 9 from Bell Labs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs)).

Once again, a public domain movie [available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln7WF78PolA):

> The film tells the story of extraterrestrials who are seeking to stop humanity from creating a doomsday weapon that could destroy the universe. The aliens implement "Plan 9", a scheme to resurrect the Earth's dead.
>
> Both Wood and his film were posthumously awarded two of Medveds' Golden Turkey Awards, as the Worst Director Ever and Worst Film, respectively.

And remember friends, future events such as these *will* affect you in the future.

Comment: +1 for 'it's time to bring out the big guns'

Answer (score 2):

## Outlander

[image: Movie Poster for Outlander]

Beowulf meets Predator.

It's got old fashioned battles, it's got sci-fi, it's got giant monsters. It's viking drinking games! It's actually got a plot!

Comment: You had me at viking drinking games. +1

Answer (score 2):

Since it's always the answer to a Story ID question except that it almost never is, I nominate *[Hardware](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099740/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*. Plus, it's pretty classic dystopic science fiction where the female lead fairly successfully defends herself from the robot attacks despite her boyfriend being the obvious designated hero of the piece.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I say we all watch *Fantastic Four*.

No, not that [*Fantastic Four*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1502712/).

No, not that [*Fantastic Four*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120667/) either.

This [*Fantastic Four*](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x19pvwt_the-fantastic-four-1994-unreleased-roger-corman_shortfilms).

Comment: Wow. No. I might even add that one to the list of things we'll never ever consider :-)

Comment: I should point out that it is widely believed to be the best *Fantastic Four* movie ever made...

Comment: That's hardly high praise.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should just cut to the chase. Forget all these mediocre or mildly bad movies, and go for the jugular.

[*Manos: Hands of Fate*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHhSS3r4OrQ)

> Manos: The Hands of Fate is a 1966 American low budget horror film written, directed, produced by, and starring Harold P. Warren. It is widely recognized to be one of the worst films ever made. [src](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manos:_The_Hands_of_Fate)

Because this film was published pre-1977, and without a copyright notice, it is in the public domain. It can be found on YouTube (the link in this post), as well as a number of other places.

Answer (score -3):

I'm going to vote for "[Real Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Steel)" with Hugh Jackman.

It's got **everything**; gigantic robots whacking at each other, a cute kid, a failed boxer and the super hot hottie who'd love him if *only he'd stop sabotaging himself*...

[image]